# Configure SOCK5 proxy in Libtorrent session (Using Python)

Tags: python, socks, libtorrent

I have been trying to configure proxy for a libtorent session; went through the documentation yet could not figure out a solution.

I tried the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068376/how-to-apply-a-proxy-in-libtorrent). Did not work for me. This is the error I got-

```
r = lt.proxy_settings()
AttributeError: module 'libtorrent' has no attribute 'proxy_settings'. Did you mean: 'pe_settings'?
```

I tried to look for `pe_settings()` is the documentation but could not find anything like that. Being hopeful, I decided to do as the error message suggests, hoping it would lead me to some other error(from where i can pick up). Hence, I changed `lt.proxy_settings()` to `lt.pe_settings()`. The error that I get now is-

```
ses.set_dht_proxy(r)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    session.set_dht_proxy(session, pe_settings)
did not match C++ signature:
    set_dht_proxy(libtorrent::session {lvalue}, libtorrent::aux::proxy_settings)
```

Mismatch in argument while trying to call the setters.

I also tried to use `settings_pack`. That did not work as well.

Here is what the session configuration looks like-

```py
ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
r = lt.pe_settings()
r.proxy_hostnames = True
r.proxy_peer_connections = True
r.hostname = self.proxy_ip
r.username = ""
r.password = ""
r.port = self.proxy_port
r.type = lt.proxy_type_t().socks5_pw
#print lt.proxy_type().socks5_pw
#ses.set_dht_proxy(r)
#ses.set_peer_proxy(r)
#ses.set_tracker_proxy(r)
#ses.set_web_seed_proxy(r)
ses.set_proxy(r)
t = ses.settings()
t.force_proxy = True
t.proxy_hostnames = True
t.proxy_peer_connections = True
#t.proxy_tracker_connections = True
t.anonymous_mode = True
ses.set_settings(t)
print (ses.get_settings())
#ses.dht_proxy()
ses.peer_proxy()
#ses.tracker_proxy()
ses.web_seed_proxy()
ses.proxy()
ses.set_settings(t)
```

Any suggestions/ comments/ insights will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Versions and platforms-

```
 1. python 3.9
 2. libtorrent 2.0.7 (installed it using vcpkg dependency manager)
 3. mac os- Monterey
```

- [Vcpkg dependency manager installation steps](https://libtorrent.org/building.html)
- [settings_pack documentation](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#default-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you configure the proxy via the same `settings_pack` all other session-wide settings are configured via. Specifically you want to set:

[proxy_hostname](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#proxy_hostname)
[proxy_port](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#proxy_port)
[proxy_type](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#proxy_type)

Maybe proxy_username and proxy_password ([docs](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#proxy_username))

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Arvid . I would really appreciate if you could please share an example on how to use `settings_pack` or any resource which I can refer to. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/RC_2_0/bindings/python/client.py#L241